# Is it possible to infer that a ParameterInfo object refers to a function pointer containing managed parameter types?

Tags: .net, reflection, c++-cli, function-pointers

I'm using reflection to examine the following method declaration and am wondering if it is possible to determine that the method's sole parameter is a function pointer.

```
public ref class T
{
public:
    void foo(Int32 (*)(String^, array<TimeSpan>^)) { }
};
```

When inspecting the `ParameterInfo` object for `foo`'s parameter, it shows that the parameter's type is `IntPtr`; this makes sense since a function pointer is not a native CLR type.

Since the function pointer contains only managed parameter types, I was hoping to get some extra context in the `ParameterInfo`.  I don't see any properties or attributes in `ParameterInfo` and `Type` that may help me distinguish this `IntPtr` instance as a function pointer -- are there any?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some thought, I'm very sure this is not possible.  Since the function argument to `foo` is a *native* pointer, the *managed* reflection system can't see beyond that layer and will always present the argument as `IntPtr`.